# Microsoft Bot v4 Skill Bot responds with 500 (Internal Server)

Tags: c#, botframework, chatbot

I am using Microsoft Bot framework v4 (CoreBot template) with Master Bot and a Child Bot.

I have modified the sample code and as able to establish the connection between the Child bot and the Master Bot. To be precise, the request from Master bot hits the Child bot successfully. But, Master bot receives 500 Internal Server error as response from the Child Bot. But the Child bot works as expected independently.

This is the error message I get at Master Bot:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

ErrorResponseException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'InternalServerError'
Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityWithHttpMessagesAsync(string conversationId, string activityId, Activity activity, Dictionary<string, List<string>> customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in Conversations.cs, line 1121
 Stack 
  Query 
  Cookies 
  Headers 


ErrorResponseException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'InternalServerError' 
Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityWithHttpMessagesAsync(string conversationId, string activityId, Activity activity, Dictionary<string, List<string>> customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in Conversations.cs
Microsoft.Bot.Connector.ConversationsExtensions.ReplyToActivityAsync(IConversations operations, string conversationId, string activityId, Activity activity, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in ConversationsExtensions.cs
Microsoft.Bot.Builder.BotFrameworkAdapter.SendActivitiesAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, Activity[] activities, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in BotFrameworkAdapter.cs
Microsoft.Bot.Builder.TurnContext+<>c__DisplayClass22_0+<<SendActivitiesAsync>g__SendActivitiesThroughAdapter|1>d.MoveNext() in TurnContext.cs
Microsoft.Bot.Builder.TurnContext.SendActivityAsync(IActivity activity, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in TurnContext.cs

MySampleBot.AdapterWithErrorHandler+<>c__DisplayClass0_0+<<-ctor>b__0>d.MoveNext() in AdapterWithErrorHandler.cs
+ 
23.  // Log any leaked exception from the application.
24.  logger.LogError(exception, $"[OnTurnError] unhandled error : {exception.Message}");
25.
26. // Send a message to the user
27. var errorMessageText = ChildBot Bot encountered an error or bug.";
28. var errorMessage = MessageFactory.Text(errorMessageText, errorMessageText, InputHints.ExpectingInput);
29. await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(errorMessage);
30.
31. errorMessageText = "To continue to run this Helpdesk Bot , please fix the bot source code.";
32. errorMessage = MessageFactory.Text(errorMessageText, errorMessageText, InputHints.ExpectingInput);
33. await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(errorMessage);
34.
35. if (conversationState != null)

Microsoft.Bot.Builder.BotAdapter.RunPipelineAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, BotCallbackHandler callback, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in BotAdapter.cs
Microsoft.Bot.Builder.BotFrameworkAdapter.ProcessActivityAsync(ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity, Activity activity, BotCallbackHandler callback, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in BotFrameworkAdapter.cs
Microsoft.Bot.Builder.BotFrameworkAdapter.ProcessActivityAsync(string authHeader, Activity activity, BotCallbackHandler callback, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in BotFrameworkAdapter.cs
Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Integration.AspNet.Core.BotFrameworkHttpAdapter.ProcessAsync(HttpRequest httpRequest, HttpResponse httpResponse, IBot bot, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in BotFrameworkHttpAdapter.cs

MySampleBot.Controllers.BotController.PostAsync() in BotController.cs
+ 
28.
29.        [HttpPost, HttpGet]
30.        public async Task PostAsync()
31.        {
32.            // Delegate the processing of the HTTP POST to the adapter.
33.            // The adapter will invoke the bot.
34.            await Adapter.ProcessAsync(Request, Response, Bot);
35.        }



lambda_method(Closure , object )

Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutorAwaitable+Awaiter.GetResult()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionMethodExecutor+AwaitableResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, object controller, object[] arguments)
System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask<TResult>.get_Result()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

Show raw exception details 

Microsoft.Bot.Schema.ErrorResponseException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'InternalServerError'

   at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityWithHttpMessagesAsync(String conversationId, String activityId, Activity activity, Dictionary`2 customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in d:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Connector\Conversations.cs:line 1121
   at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.ConversationsExtensions.ReplyToActivityAsync(IConversations operations, String conversationId, String activityId, Activity activity, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in d:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Connector\ConversationsExtensions.cs:line 241
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.BotFrameworkAdapter.SendActivitiesAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, Activity[] activities, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in d:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder\BotFrameworkAdapter.cs:line 499
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.TurnContext.<>c__DisplayClass22_0.<<SendActivitiesAsync>g__SendActivitiesThroughAdapter|1>d.MoveNext() in d:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder\TurnContext.cs:line 267

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.TurnContext.SendActivityAsync(IActivity activity, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in d:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder\TurnContext.cs:line 196

   at MySampleBot.AdapterWithErrorHandler.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<<-ctor>b__0>d.MoveNext() in C:\Users\adminMCL.PL\source\repos\MySampleBot\AdapterWithErrorHandler.cs:line 29

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.BotAdapter.RunPipelineAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, BotCallbackHandler callback, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in d:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder\BotAdapter.cs:line 210
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.BotFrameworkAdapter.ProcessActivityAsync(ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity, Activity activity, BotCallbackHandler callback, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in d:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder\BotFrameworkAdapter.cs:line 393
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.BotFrameworkAdapter.ProcessActivityAsync(String authHeader, Activity activity, BotCallbackHandler callback, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in d:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder\BotFrameworkAdapter.cs:line 363
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Integration.AspNet.Core.BotFrameworkHttpAdapter.ProcessAsync(HttpRequest httpRequest, HttpResponse httpResponse, IBot bot, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in d:\a\1\s\libraries\integration\Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Integration.AspNet.Core\BotFrameworkHttpAdapter.cs:line 133
   at MySampleBot.Controllers.BotController.PostAsync() in C:\Users\adminMCL.PL\source\repos\MySampleBot\Controllers\BotController.cs:line 34
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object )
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutorAwaitable.Awaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

What could be a possible reason for such issue ? I do not understand the root cause for this issue at the Child Bot while it works independently without any error.

Please help if you can observe if something is wrong in the code.

Thanks.

Comment: What happens when the master bot messages the child bot while the child bot is running in debug mode?

Comment: Hi Kyle, Thanks for responding. The child bot receives the message event. But during, PostAsync method, the next step goes to AdapterWithErrorHandler class where the exception is handled.

Comment: But what is the code in the child bot that's throwing the exception, and what exception is it?

Comment: await Adapter.ProcessAsync(Request, Response, Bot);

Comment: That's the entry point for your bot logic, so it's very likely that the exception is thrown somewhere else on the stack and you're just seeing it reported on `ProcessAsync`. I also asked what exception is being thrown. Can you explain how you got the line of code you just copied and pasted? Perhaps that will shed some light on how you're debugging and what information you have and what information you need.

Comment: It was just a sample code (Skills folder in bot framework solutions) that I tried to understand the master child bot communication

Comment: Are you willing to give me the information I need in order to help you understand?

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Comment: Hey @KyleDelaney, no. Got into other work without fixing this.